React Native's TouchableOpacity not taking styles by className
I'm making a custom Button component with React Native & Nativewind. But the styling doesn't work when className is applied to TouchableOpacity.
Component:
import {TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";

 <TouchableOpacity className="border border-red" {...rest}>
   <View className={cn(base(), className)}>
     {IconLeft && <IconLeft color={icon()} />}

     <Text className={text()}>
       {loading && <LoaderIcon className={spinner()} />}
       {!loading && children}
     </Text>

     {IconRight && <IconRight color={icon()} />}
   </View>
 </TouchableOpacity>


Works with style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "red" }}.  ClassName styling works normal on other components.
Tried swapping places between the inside <View /> and <TouchableOpacity /> (as suggested here). But then it becomes too small to be clicked.

The answer is: had to update Nativewind


Note : NativeWind does not work with TailwindCSS >3.3.2. If you wish
to use the most current version, please upgrade to NativeWind v4

if you already have then go through the installation of Tailwind CSS

border-red isn't a valid class in tailwind i guess... instead try border-red-50.
you can find all the available tailwind border colors here

It's in my tailwind config, just for simplification purposes
